# Performing a specific action (like setting a UIDatePicker's date) based on being segued from a specific Table View

Tags: ios, iphone, segue, uidatepicker

I have what appears to be a simple problem.

I have a table view controller (part of a 2 tabbed tab bar) which is populated by the user tapping the plus button in the navigation bar and filling in some information. That takes the user to an "Add Entry" view controller.

I have a second table view (second tab of the tab bar) which also has a plus button in the navigation bar which also calls the Add Entry. However, with this table view, I am already populating a textField and the datePicker to be related to the information it came from.

In the prepareForSegue, I'm setting the date and the text field. That works. However, I'm not entirely sure where to place the code in the Add Entry to say "If you're called from tab 1, leave everything blank and if you're called from tab 2, set the date picker".

In the prepareForSegue:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Create New Entry From Event"])
{
    AddEntryViewController *addEntryViewController = (addEntryViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    [addEntryViewController setSelectedEvent:self.occasion.title];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sectionTitle];
    [addEntryViewController setSelectedDate:dateFromString];
}
```

The setSelectedDate is:

```
- (void)setSelectedDate:(NSDate *)selectedDate
{
    _selectedDate = selectedDate;
}
```

If I set the viewWillAppear to:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.occasionTextField.text = self.selectedEvent;
    [self.datePicker setDate:self.selectedDate animated:YES];
}
```

I get a crash when calling the Add Entry from any other screen but this one which of course isn't desirable.

So I need a way to leave all text fields and the date picker as blank when called from anywhere in the app (which works without the self.datePicker line) and to only SET the datePicker when being called from THAT particular table view.

Any thoughts on this would be really great!

Comment: Create another BOOL variable in Add Entry view controller and set it in prepareForSegue then check in viewWillAppear.

Comment: @BoranA Many thanks for the reply and that does actually make sense. I'm trying to figure out a way to set it in the prepare and then check it in viewWillAppear - please could I trouble you for some potential example code of how I would be able to achieve this? It's sounding like this will work and I can then mark your answer as accepted as well

Comment: Sorry @BoranA - I have this working with your suggestion which is great news. However the weird part is, it works on the simulator, but not on the device. On the device, I get Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: date' as the error. This is very weird behaviour. Do you have any thoughts on why it would work on the simulator but not on the device?

Comment: (I could ask a new question if need be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in interface define a BOOL like this.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL fromTabOne;
```

and add

```
@synthesize fromTabOne;
```

in viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (!self.fromTabOne) {
      self.occasionTextField.text = self.selectedEvent;
      [self.datePicker setDate:self.selectedDate animated:YES];
    }
}
```

in prepareForSegue

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Create New Entry From Event"])
{
    AddEntryViewController *addEntryViewController = (addEntryViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [addEntryViewController setSelectedEvent:self.occasion.title];

    if (viewOne) { //if you're on first tab
       [addEntryViewController setFromTabOne:YES];
    } else {
       [addEntryViewController setFromTabOne:NO];
       NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
       [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, yyyy"];
       NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
       dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sectionTitle];
       [addEntryViewController setSelectedDate:dateFromString];
    }
}
```

The error you mentioned in comment probably caused by a nil NSDate or wrong locale settings. Make a nil check before setting. I guess the NSDateFormatter couldn't format your string.

Comment: Dear @BoranA - many thanks for your message and this is virtually exactly what i have in the code and it works like a charm. Many thanks for this and absolutely, as you mention, the locale is causing the issue here. I will have to figure this one out but will raise another question if need be. For now, many thanks for your help on this. This was super helpful!